# Постановка тире в предложении "если, то" с уточнениями

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос с расстановкой тире. Необходимо расставить знаки препинания в предложении "Если употреблять воду до еды - утром, в обед, вечером, а также пить воду в течение дня, то суммарно это даст необходимую дневную норму для человека". Перед "то" ставится тире?

Comment: _"Если употреблять воду до еды - утром, в обед, вечером, а также пить воду в течение дня, то суммарно это даст…"_ ===  По-моему, это даст только суммарное количество воды, выпитой человеком за сутки, но никак не _"**необходимую** дневную норму для человека"_.

Comment: Желательно, не транслировать бессмыслицу, когда не она есть предмет вопроса. Материал как иллюстрацию для вопроса надо дозировать, осмысливать и корректировать. И slava1947 правильно на это указывает. Обидно также за отвечающих на Вопрос, вынужденных закрывать глаза на глупость текстовки, в изменение которой не хочется вкладываться. И ещё. Знак тире — alt+0151.

Answer (score 2):

Тире не нужно, это СПП с придаточным условия и составным союзом ЕСЛИ...ТО.

Comment: Там другая мотивация возможна.

Comment: Мне кажется, что содержание здесь одно: вы пьете воду (когда) (1) до завтрака, обеда и ужина,  (2) а также в перерыве между едой. Присоединительный ряд явно относится к первому обстоятельству времени, а затем с помощью союза А ТАКЖЕ присоединяется второе обстоятельство времени, к которому  этот ряд уже не имеет отношения. Поэтому здесь, как мне думается, однозначный смысл, однозначная  грамматика.

Comment: Ну это только кажется. Понимаете, если бы все было так просто и однозначно, вопроса бы не возникло. А Как вы объясняете первое тире? И где тогда пара к нему? Или оно у вас тут непарное по замыслу?

Comment: Ряд имеет не добавочное, а уточняюще-пояснительное значение, это не вставка, которая выделяется тире с двух сторон. Вот пример из Розенталя: "То ли он решил, что ошибся — честного человека не распознал, то ли по другой причине, но он охотно выполнил просьбу". Пояснительный член предложения может обособляться  тире в конце предложения (таких примеров много).  Но если предложение на этом не кончается, если далее следует запятая (в соответствии с грамматикой предложения), а не точка, то ставится только одно  это тире.

Comment: *Ряд имеет не добавочное, а уточняюще-пояснительное значение* - Это что еще за терминология такая? Что такое добавочное значение? А уточняюще-пояснительное? И как вы их отличаете?

Comment: *Но если предложение на этом не кончается, если далее следует запятая (в соответствии с грамматикой предложения), а не точка, то ставится только одно это тире* - источник сией мудрой мысли? Оно-то так, тире на практике опускается, но это "правило" касается именно парного тире, а не одиночного. И только если эта запятая разделяет части ССП и СПП. И на Розенталя ссылочку не мешало бы давать. Дабы убедиться, что цитирующий не напутал.

Comment: Уточняющие и пояснительные члены предложения тесно связаны с конкретным предложением, они необходимы для понимания его смысла. Присоединительные члены - это дополнение, которое может составить содержание другого сообщения, отсюда два тире и интонация исключения.И пример из Розенталя (с одними тире) приведен.

Comment: Прямое указание на  отсутствие второго тире у Розенталя дается для приложений:  "Одно тире опускается:
1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая: Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки; Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Comment: Sergey, давайте от печки. Вы можете объяснить свою мысль, что тут не не **вводная конструкция**? И как? А то все ваши примеры никуда не годятся. После использования вами терминов типа  "добавочное" и "уточняюще-пояснительное" значение (при том, что первый зверь науке неизвестен, а "уточняющее" и "пояснительное" Розенталь последовательно разделяет), оно не мешает. Похоже, запутались Вы крепко с Розенталем.

Comment: Различие между уточняющими и пояснительными членами предложения заключается в том, что если уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому (см. § 22), то пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.==== вот это из Розенталя. http://www.web-lit.net/writer/9403/book/34923/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyiku_punktuatsiya/read/2 . Я не вижу тут ни первого, ни второго. Ну если совсем честно, то не то чтобы совсем не вижу варианта трактовки как с уточнения, но он не главный. Пояснения не вижу вовсе.

Comment: Чтобы не путаться  в частных решениях, а также неясно сформулированных и не до конца осознанных (нашими мэтрами) правилах, надо взглянуть на проблему сверху. Существует проблема выбора одного или двух тире? Несомненно, да. Например, для приложений (по Розенталю) мы выбираем одно иди два тире, а для вводных конструкций выбираем одну или две запятые, но всегда два тире.  Значит, между этими структурами есть принципиальная разница, но в правилах она не обозначена.

Comment: Что остается делать пользователю? Ему приходится или интуитивно решать эту задачу, или провести для себя какой-то анализ. Объяснить что-то другому лицу очень сложно, что мы и видим на примере данной ситуации. Наши решения, к сожалению,  не совпали, и чтобы доказать свою правоту, надо искать реальные классические тексты.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. Сочетание тире с запятой всегда было спорным моментом пунктуации. Особенно для закрывающего парного тире.

Вообще по правилам, если опустить некоторые тонкости, оба знака сохраняются, если они поставлены по разным причинам, т. е. с разной мотивацией. Но при этом на практике "закрывающее" тире почти всегда опускается, если вставная конструкция оказывается в конце составляющего предложения, т.е. перед запятой, разделяющей части ССП или СПП.

Вопрос в том, на каком основании поставлено первое тире. 
Если это тире парное, то мы имеем явный случай использования тире для обособления конструкции *утром, в обед и вечером...*, но при этом непонятно, какую конкретно часть конструкции надо обособлять c помощью этого тире..

Я думаю, что тут лучше воспользоваться скобками. В зависимости от смысла, вкладываемого автором, это может выглядеть так:

a) *Если употреблять воду до еды (утром, в обед, вечером), а также пить воду в течение дня, то суммарно это даст необходимую дневную норму для человека*.

b) *Если употреблять воду до еды (утром, в обед, вечером, а также пить воду в течение дня), то суммарно это даст необходимую дневную норму для человека*.

Если же вопрос о тире принципиальный, то в зависимости от смысла, в первом случае тире на месте скобок сохранится, во втором - нет.

a) *Если употреблять воду до еды - утром, в обед, вечером, - а также пить воду в течение дня, то суммарно это даст необходимую дневную норму для человека*.

b) *Если употреблять воду до еды - утром, в обед, вечером, а также пить воду в течение дня, то суммарно это даст необходимую дневную норму для человека*.

Скорее всего тут вариант a): по смыслу "пить воду в течение дня" не входит в поясняющую часть и тогда закрывающее тире не "поглощается" запятой.

Но, повторяю, вопрос весьма спорный, особенно для варианта b). 
В обоих случаях смотрится не очень красиво, отсюда, видимо, и вопросы. Скобки куда нагляднее.

Вообще, если вопрос принципиальный, об особенностях пунктуации при уточняющих и поясняющих конструкциях смотрите, например, тут.
http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/256-vstavnyekonstrukcii.html
Не всегда отточенные формулировки, но обилие примеров компенсирует.